# How do I filter through an ArrayList with 3 filter types defined by boolean variables?

Tags: java, arraylist

I have the main `ArrayList<Car> cars` which I am trying to filter in three different ways. Each filter can be used on its own, or can be used together.

So if there are three filters: x, y, and z, and only x and y were true, then a new array list will be considering the filters x and y and each entry will be displayed. If x, y, and z were all true then the main array list 'cars' will be filtered by all three methods and a new array list will be created and then displayed with whatever is left after all the filtering.

I have boolean instance variables for each filter which are set to true whenever the method for the specific filter is called. For example, if I was to filter the `cars` array list to see whether the car is electric or not, I would set `filterElectric = true` at the beginning of my `public void filterByElectric()` method, and then add the code where I use a for loop to check whether each `Car` object in each index position of the array list is electric or not electric.

I know I can simply make a big if statement which will allow me to say `if (filterElectric == true)` then display the new array list with the filtered cars, and I know that I can use `&&` to use multiple filters at once (if they are true) and just append the newly created array lists together and display each new filtered entry with a for loop, but doing it this way would mean I would have to make conditions for all the scenarios.

How would I be able to first check which filters out of the three are true then after I know which filter variables are set to true I can append those two filtered lists together to be displayed?

```java
    public void displayEverything() {
    if (filX == true && filY == true && filZ == true) {
        // append all filtered lists and then print newly created
        // list to system

        filtered.addAll(filX);
        filtered.addAll(filY);
        filtered.addAll(filZ);

        for (Car a : filtered) {
            System.out.println(a.disp());
        }

    } else if (filX == true && filY == true & filZ == false) {
        filtered.addAll(filX);
        filtered.addAll(filY);

        for (Car a : filtered) {
            System.out.println(a.disp());
        }
        // then it keeps going.... 
        // is there a faster way to do this 
        // instead of writing all conditions with &&'s?
    }
}


public void filterX() {
    filX = true;

    for (Car a : cars) {
        if (a.getWhatever() == 1) {
            xList.add(a);
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
}

public void filterY() {
    filY = true;

    for (Car a : cars) {
        if (a.getSomething() == true) {
            yList.add(a);
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
}

public void filZ(double a, double b) {
    filZ = true;

    for (Car a : cars) {
        if (a.getP() >= a && a.getP() <= b) {
            zList.add(a);
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post some pseudo-code? It's a bit difficult to follow

Comment: if you care about short and beautiful code, use kotlin. You could use filter on list or smth. for example, check this https://www.baeldung.com/kotlin-filter-collection

Comment: gonna edit the question now.

Comment: Take a look at my example, @ardzy

Answer (score 1):

If you want your code to be as short as possible, you can do it like this:

```
public static List<Car> filter(
    List<Car> allCars,
    boolean onlyElectric,
    boolean onlyAllWheelsDrive,
    boolean onlyAutomatic)
{
    return allCars.stream()
        .filter((Car car) -> !onlyElectric || car.isElectric())
        .filter((Car car) -> !onlyAllWheelsDrive|| car.isAllWheelsDrive())
        .filter((Car car) -> !onlyAutomatic|| car.isAutomatic())
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

The `!onlyElectric || …` looks a bit strange at first. It could be written in an alternative way:

```
    .filter((Car car) -> onlyElectric ? car.isElectric() : true)
```

This can be translated more easily into a human-understandable language: If the "onlyElectric" filter is chosen, check if the car is really electric. And if it's not chosen, just return true, which means the filter accepts every car.

In the moment you write this code, it will make sense. In a few days already, when you come back to add another filter, you will probably ask yourself: Which of the 3 boolean arguments is which, and why are they in exactly this order? An alternative solution is using an `enum` instead of these booleans.

```
public enum CarFilter {
    Electric, AllWheelsDrive, Automatic
}

public static List<Car> filter(
    List<Car> allCars,
    CarFilter... filters)
{
    EnumSet<CarFilter> set = EnumSet.noneOf(CarFilter.class);
    Collections.addAll(set, filters);

    return allCars.stream()
        .filter((Car car) -> !set.contains(CarFilter.Electric) || car.isElectric())
        .filter((Car car) -> !set.contains(CarFilter.AllWheelsDrive) || car.isAllWheelsDrive())
        .filter((Car car) -> !set.contains(CarFilter.Automatic) || car.isAutomatic())
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

That way, you can call the method like this:

```
filter(allCars, CarFilter.Electric, CarFilter.Automatic);
```

This code definitely contains more information than:

```
filter(allCars, true, false, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick solution that *might* be what you're looking for.

Start with the car:

```
package so.car;

public class Car {
    private String name;
    private boolean electric;
    private boolean awd;
    private boolean automatic;

    public Car(String name, boolean electric, boolean awd, boolean automatic) {
        this.name = name;
        this.electric = electric;
        this.awd = awd;
        this.automatic = automatic;
    }

    public boolean isElectric() {
        return electric;
    }

    public void setElectric(boolean electric) {
        this.electric = electric;
    }

    public boolean isAwd() {
        return awd;
    }

    public void setAwd(boolean awd) {
        this.awd = awd;
    }

    public boolean isAutomatic() {
        return automatic;
    }

    public void setAutomatic(boolean automatic) {
        this.automatic = automatic;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Car [name=" + name + "]";
    }

}
```

Then something to deal with running multiple filters at once:

```
package so.car;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.function.Function;

public class CarFilters {
    private Map<String, Function<Car, Boolean>> filters;

    public CarFilters(Map<String, Function<Car, Boolean>> filters) {
        this.filters = filters;
    }

    public List<String> getPassingFilterNames(Car car) {
        List<String> passingFilterNames = new ArrayList<>();

        for (Entry<String, Function<Car, Boolean>> entry : filters.entrySet()) {
            String filterName = entry.getKey();
            Function<Car, Boolean> predicateFunction = entry.getValue();

            if (predicateFunction.apply(car)) {
                passingFilterNames.add(filterName);
            }
        }

        return passingFilterNames;
    }
}
```

Finally a simple driver class:
    package so.car;

```
import java.util.AbstractMap.SimpleEntry;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, Function<Car, Boolean>> filterNameMap = new HashMap<>();
        filterNameMap.put("Electric", car -> car.isElectric());
        filterNameMap.put("All Wheel Drive", car -> car.isAwd());
        filterNameMap.put("Automatic Transmission", car -> car.isAutomatic());

        CarFilters carFilters = new CarFilters(filterNameMap);

        Car _0 = new Car("zero", true, true, true);
        Car _1 = new Car("one", true, false, true);
        Car _2 = new Car("two", false, false, true);
        Car _3 = new Car("three", true, true, true);

        List<Car> cars = new ArrayList<>();
        cars.add(_0);
        cars.add(_1);
        cars.add(_2);
        cars.add(_3);

        Map<List<String>, List<Car>> filtersAndCars = cars.stream()
                                                          .map(car -> {
                                                              List<String> filters = carFilters.getPassingFilterNames(car);

                                                              return new SimpleEntry<>(filters, new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(car)));
                                                          })
                                                          .collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue, (l1, l2) -> {
                                                              l1.addAll(l2);
                                                              return l1;
                                                          }));

        System.out.println(filtersAndCars);
    }
}
```

This will yield:

```
[Automatic Transmission]=[Car [name=two]],
[Automatic Transmission, Electric]=[Car [name=one]]
[All Wheel Drive, Automatic Transmission, Electric]=[Car [name=zero], Car [name=three]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can build a predicate based on the filtering logic you want to apply and just use this predicate to filter the stream:

```
     public Predicate<Car> filter = car ->  {
        boolean filter = true;

        if (isfilterEletricOn()) {
            filter = filter && car.isEletric();
        }

        if (isfilterOffRoadOn()) {
            filter = filter && car.isOffRoad();
        }

        if (isfilterSportOn()) {
            filter = filter && car.isSport();
        }

        return filter;
    };

    cars.stream().filter(filter).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```
public static Predicate<Car> filteringAll(boolean filterToyota, boolean filterAudi) {
        return p -> (p.getManufacturer().getName().equals("Toyota") && filterToyota) || (p.getManufacturer().getName().equals("Audi") && filterAudi);
    }
```

and use it in your code something like:

```
List<Car> listOfFilteredCars = listOfCars.stream().filter(filteringAll(false, true)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

So, if you would like to filter Audi and Toyota, you set both filter for them to true, if you would like to filter only Toyota cars, you set only toyota filter to true and audi filter to false.

Full running code:

> Main class

```
public class Main {

    List<Car> listOfCars = new ArrayList<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Car> listOfCars = new ArrayList<>();
        listOfCars.add(new Car(Manufacturer.TOYOTA, "Toyota A", 90));
        listOfCars.add(new Car(Manufacturer.TOYOTA, "Toyota B", 35));
        listOfCars.add(new Car(Manufacturer.AUDI, "Audi B", 64));
        listOfCars.add(new Car(Manufacturer.MERCEDES, "Mercedes C", 464));
        listOfCars.add(new Car(Manufacturer.TOYOTA, "Toyota C", 33));
        listOfCars.add(new Car(Manufacturer.AUDI, "Audi A", 75));
        listOfCars.add(new Car(Manufacturer.TOYOTA, "Toyota C", 23636));

        List<Car> listOfFilteredCars = listOfCars.stream().filter(filteringAll(false, true, false)).collect(Collectors.toList());

        System.out.println(listOfFilteredCars);
    }

    public static Predicate<Car> filteringAll(boolean filterToyota, boolean filterAudi, boolean filterMercedes) {
        return p -> (p.getManufacturer().equals(Manufacturer.TOYOTA) && filterToyota) || (p.getManufacturer().equals(Manufacturer.AUDI) && filterAudi) || (p.getManufacturer().equals(Manufacturer.MERCEDES) && filterMercedes) ;
    }

}
```

---

> Car class

```
public class Car {

    private Manufacturer manufacturer;
    private String nameOfTheCar;
    private double price;

    public Car() {
    }

    public Car(Manufacturer manufacturer, String nameOfTheCar) {
        this.manufacturer = manufacturer;
        this.nameOfTheCar = nameOfTheCar;
    }

     public Car(Manufacturer manufacturer, String nameOfTheCar, double price) {
        this.manufacturer = manufacturer;
        this.nameOfTheCar = nameOfTheCar;
        this.price = price;
    }

    public Manufacturer getManufacturer() {
        return manufacturer;
    }

    public String getNameOfTheCar() {
        return nameOfTheCar;
    }

    public double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(double price) {
        this.price = price;
    }



    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Manufacturer: " + getManufacturer() + ", name: " + getNameOfTheCar();
    }

}
```

---

> Manufacturer class

```
public enum Manufacturer {

    AUDI, MERCEDES, TOYOTA;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

For a more dynamic solution you can create a `MyFilter` class, which has an `active` attribute and a `filter` predicate:

```
public class MyFilter<T> {
    private boolean isActive;
    private Predicate<T> filter;
    // constructor and/or getter and setter
}
```

Now you can create a dynamic list of (in)active filters:

```
List<MyFilter<MyObject>> filters = Arrays.asList(
        new MyFilter<>(true, MyObject::isA),
        new MyFilter<>(false, MyObject::isB),
        new MyFilter<>(true, MyObject::isC)
);
```

At the end you can filter your `List<MyObject>`:

```
List<MyObject> result = objects.stream()
        .filter(o -> filters.stream().filter(MyFilter::isActive).allMatch(f -> f.getFilter().test(o)))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

To make the whole thing a bit more readable you could add a `test` method to your filter:

```
public boolean test(T object) {
    return !isActive || filter.test(object);
}
```

And filter your list with:

```
List<MyObject> result = objects.stream()
        .filter(o -> filters.stream().allMatch(f -> f.test(o)))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

If you want just one filter to match you can use `anyMatch` instead of `allMatch`. To negate the result you can use `noneMatch`.